# Rails - Call ajax request when database is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So I'm creating a basic jackpot betting site for fun and it allows users to put money into a pot and then based on the percentage of money each user puts in it randomly picks a winner. It's working fine at the moment but I feel like the way I'm updating the jackpot page with ajax is really bad. At the moment I have javascript that makes an ajax request each second to get the pot info (size of the pot, players, etc..). I feel like there is a much better way to do this. Is it possible to only make an ajax call when the database is updated? Thanks!

My javascript at the moment:

```
setInterval(update, 1000);

function update() {
getPotID();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/jackpot/update/" + potID,
    complete: function(response) {
      $('.live-jackpot').html(response.responseText);
      getPotInfo();
    },
    error: function(xhr, status,error) {
      console.log("Error");
    }
}); 
}
```

Comment: try www.pusher.com to make a real-time update.

Comment: Sockets will be your best friend, Try ActionCable in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said from [7urkm3n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2325924/7urkm3n), ActionCable has great advantage for this functionality.

Right now you are writing **Javascript** code that is executed on the client side. Every user that will start a `GET` http request to your site, will load that javascript files. They will start performing `POST` request every second to your backend server.

ActionCable is a websocket preinstalled in Rails 5. This means that to configure the notifications with ActionCable and Rails 5, you already have installed everything in your app (if you are using rails 5), you just need to install Redis on your local machine for testing the app in development.

I am not an **expert**, my understanding is that you use a specific **database** called [redis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis) to store the information about the subscription. I quote a [useful article](https://www.codementor.io/victor_hazbun/how-actioncable-uses-redis-4iq2le1i6)

> So PubSub is this concept that Redis and Postgres and a few other things supports, and basically you have this **ability to have Channels** and the ability to **subscribe** (and receive those messages) and publish to those channels and anyone listening will then receive those messages.
>
> An example of this is a ChatroomChannel, you could have people publishing messages to the ChatroomChannel and anyone who was subscribed to the ChatroomChannel would receive the broadcast from the channel with the websocket.

This is something you are missing, this way you could only find which users are actually on the playing page and which users are just browsing around, based on this `ActionCable` creates a `channel` to communicate between `server` and `client` and then creates a `subscription` to distinguish users that are actually on the playing page and those that left and should not be anymore notified

I quote another [useful article](https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable#introducing-action-cable)

> Before we dive into some code, let's take a closer look at how Action Cable opens and maintains the WebSocket connection inside our Rails 5 application.
>
> Action Cable uses the Rack socket hijacking API to take over control of connections from the application server.
>
> For every instance of your application that spins up, an instance of Action Cable is created, using Rack to open and maintain a persistent connection, and using a channel mounted on a sub-URI of your main application to stream from certain areas of your application and broadcast to other areas.

so every user that connects, `ActionCable` creates a channel that uses a specific url `localhost:3000/cable` to communicate between `server` and `client` (browser)

> Action Cable offers server-side code to broadcast certain content (think new messages or notifications) over the channel, to a subscriber. The subscriber is instantiated on the client-side with a handy JavaScript function that uses jQuery to append new content to the DOM.

This means that the server can call the client with parameters and change the page with `jquery` functions. For ex. appending a div, with a new message.

In my app https://sprachspiel.xyz I do the following in the [`MessagesController#create`](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/sprachspiel/blob/master/app/controllers/messages_controller.rb)

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast 'messages',
message: message.content,
user: message.user.name,
chatroom_id: message.chatroom_id,        
lastuser: chatroom.messages.last(2)[0].user.name
head :ok
```

so basically, I have my `message` in my controller and I can update the client by using the `ActionCable.server.broadcast` function

then in my [asset pipeline file `/app/assets/javascripts/channels/messages.js`](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/sprachspiel/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/channels/messages.js) I have the following code that trigger the change in the browser adding the message

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create('MessagesChannel', {      
  received: function(data) {
      $('#messages').append(this.renderMessage(data));
  },
  renderMessage: function(data) {
    return "<br><p> <strong>" + data.user + ": </strong>" + data.message + "</p>";
  }
});
```

I build an app called https://sprachspiel.xyz that is an actioncable app, this is the [github page for the project](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/sprachspiel), on [my portfolio](https://fabriziobertoglio.xyz/) you can read more info about my app, so please ask me anything, I'll be happy to look into it!

Good luck
Fabrizio

Comment: @RT5754 thanks for accepting my answer. I just finished editing so maybe there is new info that can help you. Contact me for help on github or hear.

Comment: Perfect! I think i'm going to do an ActionCable tutorial. Your apps look really good! I hope to be able to build stuff like that in the future! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I''l be sure to ask you if anything if I'm stuck. Followed you on GitHub. Wir konnen auch Deutsch sprechen. :)

Comment: @RT5754 ja, wenn du ein Problem hast, kannst du mich fragen !

Comment: Mach ich gerne!